# Using a Scanner with a String Splitter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use a string splitter to display user input e.g. 1,2 coordinates to display on a console. I don't get any errors when I run my code. However, my attempt to use the splitter does not seem to work.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a row and column number at which to shoot (e.g., 2,3): ");
String[] coordinates = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
if (coordinates.length != 2) {
    System.out.println("Please enter coordinates in the correct format.");
    System.out.println("\nPlayer 1 Please take your turn:");
    continue;
}

System.out.println("\nEnter Mine location:");

System.out.println("\nPlease Enter x position for your Mine:");
System.in.read(byt);
str = new String(byt);
row = Integer.parseInt(str.trim()); 

System.out.println("\nPlease Enter y position for your Mine:");
System.in.read(byt);
str = new String(byt);
col = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
```

Comment: "*does not seem to work*" doesn't tell us much. You need to be more precise about your input and what results you are getting. Also if your question is not related to compilation error post code which compiles and lets us reproduce your problem.

Comment: There's an un-matched open curly brace: `if (coordinates.length != 2) {`, an if block that does not seem to end in the posted code. Where does this if block end? Please clarify.

Comment: Since you are new to Stack Overflow you may not noticed yet that little [edit] option under this post. Use it to update your question and provide more details about problem you are facing. Also post [short, simple, but compilable example which lets us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/). Without it helping you will be very hard.

Comment: I've edited your code to show the location of the block of code that is enclosed by the if statement.

Comment: I have edited it to show where the if statement ends.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have added the where the if block ends.

Comment: I've fixed your indentation -- please take care to properly indent all code. All blocks should be indented the same amount, usually 4 spaces, so it is easy to see which code belongs to which block.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `System.in.read(...)` is dangerous code and is not doing what you think it's doing:

```
System.in.read(byt); // *****
str = new String(byt);
row = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
```

Instead use a Scanner, **something that you already have**, and either call `getNextInt()` on the Scanner, or get the line and parse it.

Also, you never use the Strings held in the coordinates array -- why get the Strings if you are ignoring them?

---

You ask about:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter a row and column number at which to shoot (e.g., 2,3): "); 
str = scanner.nextInt().split(",");
```

but then see that the compiler won't allow this since you're trying to call a method on the int primitive that `scanner.nextInt()` returns.

My recommendation to use `Scanner#nextInt()` was as a replacement for you misuse of `System.in.read(...)`. If instead you want the user to enter two numbers on one line, separated by a comma, then you're best bet is to use `String.split(",")`, although, I think it might be better to use `String.split("\\s*,\\s*")` to get rid of any white space such as spaces hanging about. This way the split should work for `1,1` as well as `1, 2` and `1  ,   2`, and then you can parse the items held in the array via `Integer.parseInt(...)`.

Comment: @I have removed the coordinates array since I realised I wasn't using it for anything. How do I implement the getNextInt() in my code?

Comment: @MickJones: You use it similar to how you call `nextLine()` on your Scanner only it returns an int, not a String. The user has to enter an int for it to work, and it is often paired with the `hasNextInt()` Scanner method to be sure that an int input exists.

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a row and column number at which to shoot (e.g., 2,3): ");
        str = scanner.nextInt().split(",");

Comment: Do you mean like that?

Comment: @MickJones: does that code work? Does it even compile (I'm thinking that it shouldn't)?

Comment: Cannot invoke split(String) on the primitive type int... That's my error at the moment. I think I am supposed to use the col and row when a user inputs them.

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter a row and column number at which to shoot (e.g., 2,3): "); 
        str = scanner.String.split(",");

Comment: @MickJones `scanner.String.split(",");` Please [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and then try again.